# Why can't sbt find main class in Java for run task?

Tags: java, scala, sbt

I have a repo containing both java and scala source code.

But in sbt interactive mode, using `show discoveredMainClasses` doesn't reveal the classes generated from java source code; particularly I cannot use `run` and select the number of a special main class to execute.

OTOH, I can use `runMain package.classname` to execute the class (yes, both scala and java files are compiled into classes correctly).

So is there any way to use `run` (with number) instead of `runMain` (with class name) to execute the java generated code that have main entry?

Comment: It does get added automatically when sbt compiles your classes...

Comment: @pfn i also think it should have. but in my case, it didnt:-( dont know why.

Comment: What sbt version do you use? Where is the main class in Java in the project structure (directory)? What's the name of the java file and the name of the class inside?

Comment: @JacekLaskowski sbtVersion is 0.13.8 (but actually it's activator). Oh, I just tried `run` on my mac and it includes those java generated classes with main entry. But strangely on my linux it doesn't (also activator with `sbtVersion` being 0.13.8). will check again when linux desktop at hand.

Comment: That's the point! "It works for me" applies so well to this case :) It worked for me at least on Mac OS X with sbt 0.13.9. It doesn't matter whether it's activator or bare sbt. They're similar as far as `run` is concerned.

Comment: @JacekLaskowski strange enough, it simply cannot find those java generated classes with main entries when running sbt run on linux, even for 0.13.9. don't know where I'm going wrong. the directory structure follows the sbt document and is *src/main/java* and *src/main/scala*.

Comment: Can you report an issue in [sbt's issue tracker](https://github.com/sbt/sbt/issues)?

Comment: @JacekLaskowski Sorry I found seems that may not be Linux relevant. I removed all the generated files (i.e., remove all files in `target` directories) and this time `discoveredMainClasses` is correct.

Comment: @JacekLaskowski Unfortunately I don't know the root cause and so I consider not to report this issue.

Answer (score 0):

I think you should be able to simply add a class like this:

```
discoveredMainClasses in Compile += "foo.Bar"
```

Comment: any way to add these automatically, when there are many these java source files?

Comment: What do you mean by automatically? I thought the problem was the entry points were _not_ automatically picked up by sbt? You can add multiple entries through `++= Seq(...)` of course. If there is a pattern you can create that sequence programmatically (like `++= (1 to 10).map { i => s"mypackage.Main$i")`. Do you mean that?